# GetFileVersionInfo equivalent in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm porting a windows application to Linux, the application fetches version from a exe using Windows `APIs GetFileVersionInfoSize()` and `GetFileVersionInfo()`. But I'm unable to find something similar to that in Linux.

I'm aware that I can use `readelf` to read contents of application or object files in Linux as below

```
[root@Panch-Linux]# readelf <xyz.so> -h
  ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - Linux
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x4f7ec0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          17823344 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         38
  Section header string table index: 35
```

Shoud I use `readelf` to get the version information, if yes then the string "Version" is the one which actually represents the file version. Also please let me know how to use `readelf` in C++ programming on Linux environment.

If this is not the right way, please suggest me appropriate way of doing this.

Comment: Presumably the source code to `readelf` is available, Linux being open-source and all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format  looks like the version information in the ELF header is the version of ELF.  Most Linux executable(s) encode their version in the file name (or directory) and use a soft link to provide a version agnostic filename.